# How to reiterate while loop containing scanner in order to restart code in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Basically the issue is that once the main method completes, it prompts to restart the code or not, except it terminates after prompting, no matter what I enter. How do I fix this?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class PasteTyper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         while (true) { 
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.print("\nEnter what to paste: ");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\nEnter typing speed (10 is reccommended) (Lower is faster, higher is slower): ");
            int speed = scan.nextInt();
            try{Thread.sleep(3000);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
            
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
                try{Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(30 * speed));} catch(InterruptedException e){}
                int delete = rand.nextInt(20 * speed);
                if(delete == 5){
                    int randomChar = rand.nextInt(10);
                    switch(randomChar){
                        case 1: convert('a'); break;
                        case 2: convert('b'); break;
                        case 3: convert('c'); break;
                        case 4: convert('d'); break;
                        case 5: convert('e'); break;
                        case 6: convert('f'); break;
                        case 7: convert('g'); break;
                        case 8: convert('h'); break;
                        case 9: convert('i'); break;
                        default:convert('j'); break;
                    }
                    try{Thread.sleep(40 * speed);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
                    doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                    try{Thread.sleep(20 * speed);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
                }
                if(input.charAt(i) == '\\') {
                    if(input.charAt(i + 1) == 't') {
                        convert('\t');
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if(input.charAt(i + 1) == 'n') {
                        convert('\n');
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                        convert(input.charAt(i));
                }   
                else
                    convert(input.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to paste again? (y/n): ");
            String choice = scan.next();
            if(!choice.equals("y"))
                break;
         }
            
         scan.close();
    }
    
    public static void convert(char character){
            switch(character){
                case '\t' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                case '\n' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                case 'a' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                case 'b' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_B);
                case 'c' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                case 'd' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                case 'e' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_E);
                case 'f' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_F);
                case 'g' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_G);
                case 'h' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_H);
                case 'i' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_I);
                case 'j' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_J);
                case 'k' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_K);
                case 'l' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_L);
                case 'm' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_M);
                case 'n' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_N);
                case 'o' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_O);
                case 'p' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_P);
                case 'q' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                case 'r' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                case 's' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                case 't' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_T);
                case 'u' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_U);
                case 'v' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                case 'w' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                case 'x' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_X);
                case 'y' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
                case 'z' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
                case 'A' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_A);
                case 'B' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_B);
                case 'C' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_C);
                case 'D' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_D);
                case 'E' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_E);
                case 'F' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_F);
                case 'G' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_G);
                case 'H' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_H);
                case 'I' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_I);
                case 'J' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_J);
                case 'K' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_K);
                case 'L' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_L);
                case 'M' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_M);
                case 'N' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_N);
                case 'O' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_O);
                case 'P' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_P);
                case 'Q' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                case 'R' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_R);
                case 'S' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_S);
                case 'T' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_T);
                case 'U' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_U);
                case 'V' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_V);
                case 'W' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_W);
                case 'X' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_X);
                case 'Y' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Y);
                case 'Z' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Z);
                case '`' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                case '0' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_0);
                case '1' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                case '2' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_2);
                case '3' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_3);
                case '4' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                case '5' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                case '6' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_6);
                case '7' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_7);
                case '8' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_8);
                case '9' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_9);
                case '-' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                case '=' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
                case '~' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                case '!' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_1);
                case '@' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_2);
                case '#' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_3);
                case '$' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_4);
                case '%' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_5);
                case '^' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_6);
                case '&' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_7);
                case '*' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_8);
                case '(' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_9);
                case ')' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_0);
                case '_' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                case '+' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
                case '[' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                case ']' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
                case '\\' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
                case '{' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                case '}' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
                case '|' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
                case ';' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                case ':' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT,KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                case '\'' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
                case '"' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
                case ',' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
                case '<' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
                case '.' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                case '>' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                case '/' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                case '?' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
                case ' ' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
               
            }
        } 
        
        public static void doType(int keycode){
            try{
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(keycode);
                robot.keyRelease(keycode);
            }
            catch(AWTException e){}
        }
        public static void doType(int keycode1, int keycode2){
            try{
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(keycode1);
                robot.keyPress(keycode2);
                robot.keyRelease(keycode1);
                robot.keyRelease(keycode2);
            }
            catch(AWTException e){}
        }
}
```

I tried making the main method its own method, then calling the method within a while loop in the main method. All the same result.

Comment: Where is the convert method code? And what does it do? Also, please look at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo), because this code looks to be at risk of running into the issue.

Comment: ... and where is the `doType(...)` method code? And how is this code misbehaving specifically? And what are the results of your own debugging attempts? This question is a bit incomplete.

Comment: Its included in the rest of the code, do you need it? It works fine so I don't believe that would be the issue.

Comment: We can't run or compile the code in its present state. How can we test it and know what the problem is if it is uncompilable and un-runnable?

Comment: I updated it, try now. The code will type out what you paste. Then when it prompts to restart, no matter what you enter, it terminates. otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Yes, check the duplicate. Your code does in fact need to fix how your Scanner is handling the end-of-line tokens. In the future, please strive to post a [mre] program with your question if you're asking about behavioral issues. It will help remove this unnecessary back-and-forth. Also, please check out the [tour].

Comment: FYI, you can replace your switch with `doType(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar('a' + rand.nextInt(10)))`